# TableView not displaying data

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to get this table view to work, but for some reason, when I run the program, the table is empty.  I compared it several times with the example given in the Oracle and the Youtube tutorial, but I cannot figure out what I am missing.

The code compiles without errors. Here it is:

```
public class JavaFXcourseNewBoston extends Application {

Stage window;
TableView<Person> table;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args); // übernimmt den String args aus main      
}

@Override
public void start(Stage ersteStage) throws Exception {
    window = ersteStage;
    window.setTitle("Tables!");

    // public Person(String fName, String lName, int age)
    //TableColumn first name
    TableColumn<Person, String> fnameC = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    fnameC.setMinWidth(100);
    fnameC.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fName"));

    //TableColumn last name 
    TableColumn<Person, String> lnameC = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lnameC.setMinWidth(100);
    lnameC.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lName"));

    //TableColumn age
    // WRAPPER NOT PRIMITIVE DATA TYPES!! 
    TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageC = new TableColumn<>("Age");
    ageC.setMinWidth(50);
    ageC.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));

    table = new TableView<>();
    table.setItems(getP());
    table.getColumns().addAll( fnameC, lnameC, ageC); 

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);

    //initialize window
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 250);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

public ObservableList<Person> getP() {
    ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    persons.add(new Person("Lisa", "Simpson", 10));
    persons.add(new Person("Bart", "Simpson", 12));
    persons.add(new Person("Marge", "Simpson", 32));
    persons.add(new Person("Homer", "Simpson", 35));
    persons.add(new Person("Maggie", "Simpson", 2));

    return persons;
}

}// end class
```

And the Person class:

```
public class Person {

String fName;
String lName;
int age;

Person(String fName, String lName, int age) 
{
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
    this.age = age;                  
}
}
```

(I didn't write any getters and setters for Person since they aren't needed here.)

I have been trying to solve this for 2 hours (yes, really) and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Re the GUI component toolkit. Is this using Java-FX? Android? ..

Comment: NNo, I am not using android - this is just a project in NetBeans, trying my best to learn JavaFX.